# How to consume different commands in different microservices using Axon?

Tags: event-sourcing, axon

I have 2 different microservices **todo-service** and **validation-service** and command types `CreateTodoCommand` and `ValidateTodoCommand`.

If I have one command handler in one service and another one in the second service I receive `No node known to accept` exception on sending a command that the service is not aware of.

Can I split my `@CommandHandler`s to have them in different services?

Comment: It should be ok to have them in a  separate service. From domain boundary perspective, the validation-service should only do validatePayload(rawInput) and pass the validated value to the Todo-Service as CreateTodoCmd(validatedPayload)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's definitely possible @Stephan.
Assuming you're in a Spring Boot environment, the only thing you have to do is set the right dependency for the type of `DistributedCommandBus` you want (thus SpringCloud or JGroups) and set the `axon.distributed.enabled` property to `true`.

The framework will automatically search for all the `@CommandHandler` annotated functions. If your application still states it cannot find 'a node to expect the command', then something fails during the wiring process.

Or simpler put, I can think of two reasons:
1) Your `@CommandHandler` annotated functions aren't registered to the `DistributedCommandBus`.
2) The message-handling information isn't shared between your nodes.

Any how, the simple answer to your question is: yes, you can have your `@CommandHandler` annotated functions in different services.

Why it isn't working though, is something different.

Comment: I wonder if you have a code sample for `DistributedCommandBus` somewhere on github?

Comment: I don't have one openly available, but like I pointed out, setting up should be very simple in a Spring Boot environment. So to help you further with this: Are you using Spring Boot?